# How do I match Group 0 to cover the last parenthese in string

Tags: regex

Find a regex that matches 3 formats of a single string

Current solution: `/.?import\(?.((\w+) +from )?([\'\"])(.*)\3/gm`

https://regex101.com/r/ieLGTF/1

[image]

I need to keep everything the same in terms of matched groups, but for the third string, group 0 should include that last ")". I suppose it doesnt necessarily need to be part of group 0, but it cannot be part of any other existing group, so making a new group 5+ would be acceptable.

Comment: Capture group numbers start at 1, what do you mean by group 0?

Comment: Try adding `\)?` at the end.

Comment: @Barmar When I hover over the blue area in the site, it says "Group 0", so thats where thats coming from. I suppose it's the match?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 
```.?import\(?.((\w+) +from )?([\'\"])(.*)\)?\3``` does not get it :/

Comment: `\)?` should be after `\3`

Answer (score 2):

Add `\)?` at the end to match an optional `)`.

```
/.?import\(?.((\w+) +from )?([\'\"])(.*)\3\)?/gm
```